# Javascript/Jquery Internet Explorer issue in showing divs upon click

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-10

I'm currently experiencing an issue with my code. I have a form, which consists of multiple checkboxes. These checkboxes open if you click on the box itself or on the labels within. If you click, another div is shown cancel_body. This shows a list of options which aren't really related to the form results, just to show info for the user. My problem is that in IE it doesnt work as expected. You can click on checkbox, it ticks, but nothing shows. Click several more times then it shows. There is no pattern that I can make out. Does anyone have any idea why this may happen?

Thank you!

```
  $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function () {
     if ($(this).attr("checked")) {
         $(this).parent().next(".cancel_body").show(600);
     }else{
         $(this).parent().next(".cancel_body").hide(600);
     };
  });
```

Comment: I've only tested this in ie10

Comment: can you create the fiddle.

Comment: Try changing attr() to prop()

Comment: You should use `prop()` instead of `attr()` for Boolean values. I don't know if this is causing the problem.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `.prop`, not `.attr`? I'm surprised it works on any browser.

Comment: Or just `this.checked`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `prop()` instead of `attr()` for Boolean values:

```
if ( $(this).prop("checked") )
    ...
```

`attr()` will return `undefined` if the `checked` attribute is not present on the element, and `"checked"` if it is present, regardless of whether it's set to true or false: http://jsfiddle.net/yz4K6/

However as Barmar has mentioned in comments, you can simply use `this.checked` instead:

```
if ( this.checked )
    ...
```

Comment: Hi, I'm afraid if i add .prop. The hidden div doesnt show. If I do the this.checked, it shows then hides again.

My script pulls the "reasons" (checkboxes) from a database, so number is unknown.

Here is the jfiddle. But I can't get it to work properly on there either!! http://jsfiddle.net/F68Kh/

Comment: Ahhh, my problem with .prop is the code I was required to use had a very outdated jquery (pre 1.6 when .prop was introduced for it). I have since updated for my purposes. Thank you very much!